# django [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/html/sp-django-master/static/CACHE'

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to install SASS on my django app but keeping getting this error. Although, it works fine on my local environment but doesn't work on my test server on an AWS Ubuntu AMI. I've this in one of my templates:

```
{% load compress %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% compress css %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/scss" href="{% static 'm1/scss/style.scss' %}" />
{% endcompress %}
```

I get the error on the `{% compress css %}` line

## settings.py

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    "compressor",
)

COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (
    ('text/scss', 'sass --scss {infile} {outfile}'),
)
```

Local env settings:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'static/m1/'
```

Test env settings:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/html/sp-django-master/static/'
```

Comment: Does the user owning the Django process have write permissions on that directory?

Comment: not sure. How can I check that?

Comment: ls -l /var/www/html/sp-django-master/static/CACHE/ will show the owner / permissions for that directory.
(you might want to include your apache [assuming, since /var/www/html is the canonical apache location] wsgi.conf or however you're deploying this, but unless you specified an alternate user, I would expect the Django process user to be the same as the user running apache (apache for RHEL/Fedora, forget for Debian/Ubuntu)

Comment: thanks that resolved the error issue. But sass is still not working. I viewed source and I can see it's generating a CSS. But when clicked on it says 404 Not found The requested URL /static/CACHE/css/style.e0e25ebe05de.css was not found on this server. Although I've looked through the terminal and the file does exist there! I don't know why the server is saying 404 not found

Answer (score -4):

you can just

```
chmod 777 /var/www/html/sp-django-master/static/CACHE
chmod 777 /var/www/html/sp-django-master/static/CACHE/*
```

then restart 
But it is UNSAFE! 
You can create a group and assign apache to it, then change owner of a folder to a group.

Comment: Ugh... if you drive a car and it's leaking oil, do you just keep refilling it with oil every time you hit a traffic light?

Comment: This is unsafe. Anyone with (non-root) access to the server would be able to inject whatever they want to your page.

Comment: @Pithikos Please suggest a proper solution